# tableView Cell not displaying data, What's the issue? (Swift 3)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cocoa-touch, alamofire

So I have a view controller that is parsing some bitcoin price data. The function successfully responds and parses the data, but I cannot seem to get it to display in tableView.

I have already tested the outlets and identities via a test cell, which *does* work.

What am I doing wrong?

Code: `

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import AlamofireObjectMapper
import ObjectMapper

class Response: Mappable{
    var data: [Amount]?

 required init?(map: Map){

}
    func mapping(map: Map) {
    data <- map["data"]
   }
}

class Amount: Mappable {
    var data : String?

    required init?(map: Map){

}
    func mapping(map: Map) {
    data <- map["data.amount"]
   }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, 
UITableViewDataSource {
    var mount = [String]()
    var am = [String]()



    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!


func Call_bitcoin() {
    let url = "https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/BTC-USD/buy"
    Alamofire.request(url).responseObject{ (response: DataResponse<Amount>) in
        let mount = response.result.value
        let am = mount?.data


        self.tableView.reloadData()

        return


    }
}





    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    Call_bitcoin()
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return am.count
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("You tapped cell number \(indexPath.row).")
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

    print(am)
    cell.textLabel?.text = am[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

}
```

`

Comment: Have you set `tableView.dataSource = self` and `tableView.delegate = self`?

Comment: If your cells are not visible probably `am.count` returned 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to add elements in your `Call_bitcoin()` function but you are doing it wrong. You have already created `var am = [String]()`. So you don't need to use `let am = mount?.data`. You could add your data in your `am` variable which is already created. You need to change some of your code lines in `Call_bitcoin()` function:

From:

```
let mount = response.result.value
let am = mount?.data
```

To:

```
let mount = response.result.value
am.append(mount?.data) // This part should be set by your 'mount?.data' value type
```

Comment: Thank you!! This was mostly correct. Xcode yelled at me and turned it into this:     self.am.append((mount?.data)!)

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON not returning array, it's having dictionary.that why you get

```
am.count = 0
```

Solve first your data and put data into the array.

```
 {"data":{"amount":"2414.88","currency":"USD"},"warnings":[{"id":"missing_version","message":"Please supply API version (YYYY-MM-DD) as CB-VERSION header","url":"https://developers.coinbase.com/api#versioning"}]}
```